# Match and merge from multiple files with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a directory with a bunch of "logins" json files like this:

```
[
 {
    "user_id": "5ce722b803b54f03f745cdf45d579920",
    "time": "2019-10-29T20:03:18.894006Z"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "5ce722b858f3e80e6e85aad3113a1665",
    "time": "2019-10-29T20:11:32.4843Z"
  }
]
```

In another directory I have a bunch of "users" json files like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "5ce722b803b54f03f745cdf45d579920",
    "email": "foo@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "enabled": true,
    "created_at": "2019-06-13T17:07:17.2925Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-06-13T17:15:20.903085Z",
    "groups": {
      "count": 1,
      "shortlist": [
        {
          "id": "5d0282c5d5d6063286140e864a0c6506",
          "name": "cool users",
          "description": "cool users",
          "locked": true
        }
      ]
    },
    "avatar": "",
    "role_id": "5d0282c488bba9ebc62df8b3c38571a9",
    "company_uid": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "5d0284fdec62d47039e7119013b0aa2c",
    "email": "bar@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "Jane",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "enabled": true,
    "created_at": "2019-06-13T17:16:45.210018Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-06-13T17:16:45.210018Z",
    "groups": {
      "count": 1,
      "shortlist": [
        {
          "id": "5d0282c5d5d6063286140e864a0c6506",
          "name": "cool users",
          "description": "cool users",
          "locked": true
        }
      ]
    },
    "avatar": "",
    "role_id": "5d0282c488bba9ebc62df8b3c38571a9",
    "company_uid": ""
  }
]
```

What I'm trying to do with jq is:

1. For each `user_id` in the "Logins" files, I want to find a matching `id` in the "Users" files.
2. I want to merge those two object together.

The intended outcome is another json file(s), which contains login and corresponding user data. As a bonus, I only want the email first and last name from "Users".

End result would be something like this:

```
[
 {
    "user_id": "5ce722b803b54f03f745cdf45d579920",
    "time": "2019-10-29T20:03:18.894006Z",
    "email": "foo@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe"
  }
}
```

I've tried variations of the below, but end up with what looks like an infinite loop or something. I know my for loops are wrong, just not sure how to work with multiple files like this.

```
lastlogins="/last10/*.json"
users="/users/*.json"
for ll in $lastlogins; do
  for user in $users; do
    userid=$(jq -r '.[].user_id' $ll)
    jq -c --arg userid "$userid" '.[] | select(.id == $userid)' $user
  done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use shell looping.  That is, everything can be done using jq.

For example, using the invocation:

```
jq -f users-logins.jq --argfile users users.json logins.json
```

where users-logins.jq contains:

```
INDEX($users[]; .id) as $udict
| map( if $udict[.user_id] then . + $udict[.user_id] else empty end)
| map( {user_id, time, email, first_name, last_name} )
```

the output using the sample inputs would be:

```
[
  {
    "user_id": "5ce722b803b54f03f745cdf45d579920",
    "time": "2019-10-29T20:03:18.894006Z",
    "email": "foo@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe"
  }
]
```

Comment: Looks promising. I can't see how this is going to parse all of the files in each directory. This is not working for me as posted. I'm getting errors like `jq: Bad JSON in` though I know the json in `users.json` is valid.

Comment: Regarding `Bad JSON`, what does `jq empty *.json` give? As for having multiple files and directories, you didn't specify any details about that, so there's not much I can do at this point besides suggesting you look at the jq manual.

Comment: `jq empty *.json` returns nothing. The multiple files requirement is mentioned clearly in the title and description (a few times). Thank you for you help though :)

Comment: You didn't give details or examples about the multiple files/directories -- see [mcve] -- but in any case, you should be able to adapt the illustrative solution to your actual needs.