# Merge two files with different object types (patients and address)

Tags: json, file, join, merge, jq

I've two files:

- patient.json: patients themselves
- address.json: address of patients

Each address patient contains its patient id.

`patients.json`:

```json
{
  id: 1,
  name: "name1"
}
{
  id: 2,
  name: "name2"
}
```

`patient_address.json`:

```json
{
  patient_id: 1,
  city: "city1-1",
  town: "town1-1"
}
{
  patient_id: 1,
  city: "city1-2",
  town: "town1-2"
}
{
  patient_id: 2,
  city: "city2-1",
  town: "town2-1"
}
```

My desired result would be:

```json
{
  id: 1,
  name: "name1",
  address: [
  {
    city: "city1-1",
    town: "town1-1"
  },
  {
    city: "city1-2",
    town: "town1-2"
  }]
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: "name2",
  address: [
  {
    city: "city2-1",
    town: "town2-1"
  }]
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try anything to solve this on your own?

Comment: No, sorry. I've tried to get some help looking at some documentation, but I don't quite figure out how to begin with that...

Comment: Did you lookup similar questions on the subject, in the site?

Comment: Yes, yes, but I've been able to look up any related post approach...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60663178/match-and-merge-from-multiple-files-with-jq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input files and the expected output are invalid as JSON, but ignoring that for the moment, you can use jq to produce the desired transformation as follows:

```
< patients.json jq --slurpfile address patient_address.json '
  (reduce $address[] as $a ({}; 
     .[ ($a.patient_id)|tostring].address += [$a | {city,town}] )) as $dict
  | . + $dict[.id|tostring]  
'
```

Output:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "name1",
  "address": [
    {
      "city": "city1-1",
      "town": "town1-1"
    },
    {
      "city": "city1-2",
      "town": "town1-2"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "name2",
  "address": [
    {
      "city": "city2-1",
      "town": "town2-1"
    }
  ]
}
```

There are several ways to convert your inputs to JSON, e.g. using [hjson](/questions/tagged/hjson) or similar tools.  Similarly, if you want the output to be a JSON array, you have several options, e.g. using `map`.

Caveat: The solution presented above assumes that `.id|tostring` will not have any collisions.  This would be the case, for example, if .id is always an integer.